# swift breaks into infinite loop after conforming to Stridable

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, stride

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Rank: CaseIterable {
case Ace, King, Queen, ...
}
```

and want to make it conform to `Stridable`. I tried to implement the func `distance(to other: _)` by getting the index of the card like so:

```
func distance(to other: Rank) -> Int {
            let indexOfSelf = Rank.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
            let indexOfOther = Rank.allCases.firstIndex(of: other)!
            return indexOfOther - indexOfSelf
}
```

This works fine and as intended as long as I don't conform to Stridable, e.g. `ace.distanceTo(Queen)` results in 2. However, as soon as I conform to `Stridable`, the code breaks into an infinite loop and I get the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=x)`.

Is that supposed to happen? And if so, why is that happening?

Thanks for all help!

My implementation of `advanced(by n: Int)`:

```
func advanced(by n: Int) -> Rank {
            let index = Rank.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
            let resultIndex = index + n
            if resultIndex > Rank.allCases.count {
                return .Two
            }
            return Rank.allCases[resultIndex]
}
```

something that would cause the error:

call of: `ace.distanceTo(Queen)` would break into an infinite loop

Comment: Can you provide your implementation of `func advanced(by n: Int) -> Rank`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of the [Strideable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/strideable) protocol:

> **Important**
>
> The Strideable protocol provides default implementations for the equal-to (==) and less-than (<) operators that depend on the Stride type’s implementations. If a type conforming to Strideable is its own Stride type, it must provide concrete implementations of the two operators to avoid infinite recursion.

In your case `Rank` is not it's own `Stride` type, but the `distance(to:)` method calls `firstIndex(of:)`, which calls `==` on the elements. Now `==` has a special implementation for `Strideable` types which – as we can see from the implementation in [Stride.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift#L159)– calls `distance(to:)`. That leads to an “infinite” recursion, and ultimately to an stack overflow. You can also see that from the stack backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3fffb8)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100001b4b test`Rank.distance(other=ace, self=king) at main.swift:11
    frame #1: 0x0000000100001fd8 test`protocol witness for Strideable.distance(to:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #2: 0x00007fff7ac4927b libswiftCore.dylib`static (extension in Swift):Swift.Strideable.== infix(A, A) -> Swift.Bool + 219
    frame #3: 0x0000000100001f56 test`protocol witness for static Equatable.== infix(_:_:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #4: 0x00007fff7ab25ea9 libswiftCore.dylib`(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection< where A.Element: Swift.Equatable>.firstIndex(of: A.Element) -> Swift.Optional<A.Index> + 905
    frame #5: 0x0000000100001c31 test`Rank.distance(other=ace, self=ace) at main.swift:12:49
    ...
    frame #42256: 0x0000000100001fd8 test`protocol witness for Strideable.distance(to:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #42257: 0x00007fff7ac4927b libswiftCore.dylib`static (extension in Swift):Swift.Strideable.== infix(A, A) -> Swift.Bool + 219
    frame #42258: 0x0000000100001f56 test`protocol witness for static Equatable.== infix(_:_:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #42259: 0x00007fff7ab25ea9 libswiftCore.dylib`(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection< where A.Element: Swift.Equatable>.firstIndex(of: A.Element) -> Swift.Optional<A.Index> + 905
    frame #42260: 0x0000000100001c31 test`Rank.distance(other=ace, self=ace) at main.swift:12:49
    frame #42261: 0x0000000100001fd8 test`protocol witness for Strideable.distance(to:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #42262: 0x00007fff7ac4927b libswiftCore.dylib`static (extension in Swift):Swift.Strideable.== infix(A, A) -> Swift.Bool + 219
    frame #42263: 0x0000000100001f56 test`protocol witness for static Equatable.== infix(_:_:) in conformance Rank at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #42264: 0x00007fff7ab25ea9 libswiftCore.dylib`(extension in Swift):Swift.Collection< where A.Element: Swift.Equatable>.firstIndex(of: A.Element) -> Swift.Optional<A.Index> + 905
    frame #42265: 0x0000000100001c31 test`Rank.distance(other=queen, self=ace) at main.swift:12:49
    frame #42266: 0x0000000100001830 test`main at main.swift:23:18
    frame #42267: 0x00007fff7b3843d5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

As Joakim said, the easiest solution is to implement those methods based on the enums's raw values, this avoids the (recursive) use of `==`:

```
enum Rank: Int, Strideable {
    case ace, king, queen, jack
    
    func advanced(by n: Int) -> Rank {
        return Self(rawValue: self.rawValue + n)!
    }
    
    func distance(to other: Rank) -> Int {
        return other.rawValue - self.rawValue
    }
}
```

This is also more efficient than looking up the values in the `allCases` collection again and again.